# Select count & count division by sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got such a script. It returns the value of requests done by employees. Id like to divide the 2nd table result by the number of days "(sysdate-entrydate)" but it returns an error its not a group by function. Id like to have 3 tables in the result. I thought of subquery but the query I wanted to nest doesnt work (count divided by sysdate-entrydate). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
select username, count(username)
from requesttool.request_queue
inner join requesttool.request_detail 
on requesttool.request_detail.request_id = requesttool.request_queue.request_id

inner join TASKTOOL.task_source_type_codes
on requesttool.request_queue.request_source_id = tasktool.task_source_type_codes.task_source_id

inner join admin.users 
on coalesce(requesttool.request_queue.REASSIGNED_ANALYST_ID,requesttool.request_queue.ASSIGNED_ANALYST_ID) = admin.users.userid

where ATTRIBUTE_ID = 259

and STATUS_ID in ('3','4')
group by username
```

2nd script (not working):

```
select username, count (username), count(username)/(sysdate-entrydate)
from requesttool.request_queue
inner join requesttool.request_detail 
on requesttool.request_detail.request_id = requesttool.request_queue.request_id

 inner join TASKTOOL.task_source_type_codes
on requesttool.request_queue.request_source_id = tasktool.task_source_type_codes.task_source_id

inner join admin.users 
on coalesce(requesttool.request_queue.REASSIGNED_ANALYST_ID,requesttool.request_queue.ASSIGNED_ANALYST_ID) = admin.users.userid

where ATTRIBUTE_ID = 259

and STATUS_ID in ('3','4')

group by username
order by count(username) desc
```

Example:

```
Mr A has 10,000 requests done joined 6 years ago (2190 days)
Mr B has 1,000 requests done but joined 1 year ago

Username // Count (username) // Average per day
Mr A // 10,000 // 4.56 (10000 / 2190 = 4.65 requests a day)
Mr B // 1,000 // 2.73 (1000 / 365 = 2.73 requests a day)
```

Solution:
    **group by username, entrydate**

Comment: Each row for the user name will have a different entry date, so which one would you use? What result would you expect to see? It can be useful to take a small sample of records and try to work out what you need manually first, then figure out how to translate that to SQL.

Comment: Hello, thats correct. Ill explain. I've made the script to calculate how much work did each employee do, but employees joined at different dates so Id like to count how many requests have they made per day on average, ie:

Mr A has 10,000 requests done joined 3 years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your post, I guess `entrydate` is a property of the user.  So that for one `username` there is only one `entrydate`.  But Oracle doesn't know that, so it gives an error that it cannot tell which `entrydate` to use.

You can solve this issue by grouping on `(username, entrydate)`.  This lets Oracle know there's only one `entrydate` per group:

```
group by username, entrydate
```